Sloping Second Floor
We are inheriting a house built in 1970. It has a slab foundation which is still level. However the second floor (vinyl plank) has a significant slope downward in the front half of the house and there are lots of uneven spots otherwise. Adding there is a deck over the garage in the front (in front of the sloping rooms), which is relatively even and I believe has had the joists sistered, to stop the water that was pooling towards the second floor. Additionally the deck is a big higher than the floor and I assume this is because the floor has dropped.
How do we go about fixing the floor? Who do we contact? We are in a VHCOL area and manual labor is on the high side. We are saving about $10k a year moving in vs renting it out, but I don’t want the floors to drive me crazy living there. Plus we need to know how much this is going to cost to fix to argue against the trust valuation which was just someone driving by, taking a pic and giving us the same value as a recent sale of a nicely remodeled house with the same floor plan but with an addition .

The reason for the slope will matter.  Simple matter of mis-calculation or more of a sinking reason will affect the costs.  70s should have decent building codes(but not as good as insulation codes).   Depending on the slope, it might matter more to a pool table than to a bedroom, unless it makes you seasick walking over it.

how is the ceiling on first floor

We really need measurements. Words like "significant" are relative.  This may be a structural issue or something that can be remedied easily.

I’m prone to migraines & car sickness, etc so more sensitive than others may be.
The ceiling below is fine inside. The drywall that is in the garage has mold and will be removed in a week so I’ll be able to see what’s going on with the joists and the beam, but I don’t know that it’ll mean much to me.
I don’t know what tools I have that I can measure the slope with. I may be able to find a laser level.

You have a very complex issue with no pictures or data.   I am not sure how anyone is supposed to help or give you an answer.   Reading through your question I am not even sure what the problem is.   Floors get out of whack for TONS of reasons.   Also your second floor sloping isn't vinyl plank.   It has a subfloor and joists under it.    Vinyl planks can't cause sloping, but the joists can.    Provide some pictures, measurements and all that and I am sure someone can help.

You need a general contractor with a structural engineer on speed dial.
Write a contract for exploration at a minimum. Once you understand the underlying cause, you can get quotes from multiple companies, which will feed into your valuation question.
Personal anecdote: I lived with a massive slope for about a decade… it only got fixed when I sold the house.

I'm living with a significant slope now. I know why it happened, I trust that the changes made since then will keep it from subsiding further, and I just work around it, shimming furniture legs to compensate in the worst affected areas The price was right even with this nuisance..
